# IntelliJ replaces method parameter names of interface

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am having problems with local variable names of methods that are in interface in program Intellij IDEA (look at screens below). Name of variables are "s1", "s2" instead of correct names that I have set in interface.

Interface class is in other .jar that is added in project structure's artifacts.

I completely do not know how to fix this problem.

How it looks in editor when I want to use method:

[image]

How it looks in interface:

[image]

How it looks in class that implements interface:

[image]

Comment: Note that you do not need to write `public` to methods in interfaces. The methods automatically inherit the visibility of the interface. So if your interface is `public`, all methods are too.

Comment: You should file a bug report to Jetbrains Youtrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues). This is not a SO question.

Comment: Please post _text_ and not _images_

Comment: I have previously posted text images (hyperlinks) but someone edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing this stuff from a **compiled jar**.

Classes, once compiled, don't really contain the original variable names any more. They don't store the javadocs either.

What you want to do is build a separate jar with javadocs only and import it into your project (if you use maven, it can be done with the following plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html) or if you have access to the source code of your library, you can go to *File > Project structure* and add the reference to the source code.